# is it possible to create partition table inside crypt mapper?

Tags: fdisk, cryptsetup, partition-table

i.e. not

`fdisk /dev/sda; cryptsetup create xxx /dev/sda1`

but vice versa

`cryptsetup create xxx /dev/sda ; fdisk /dev/mapper/xxx`

is it allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but might need additional steps (kpartx) to make those partitions available.

```
parted /dev/mapper/cryptsda
kpartx -a /dev/mapper/cryptsda
mount /dev/mapper/cryptsda1 /mnt/firstpartition
```

Most people just use LVM instead, of course LVM also needs VG/LV to be enabled first, but this is usually handled for you by whatever init system you use.

However, you should still partition the raw drive regardless, otherwise there is a high risk of data loss. A seemingly unpartitioned drive is fair game for all partitioners, installers, etc.

So usually it's `/dev/sda` » `/dev/sda1` » cryptsetup/LUKS » LVM » filesystem.