# Parted on /dev/mapper/, What are the differences between Ignore and Cancel?

Tags: parted, device-mapper

I am using `parted` to partition a `/dev/mapper/luks_device`. I know that I have to use `kpartx` to load the partition mappings afterwards (with reference to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409325/150246)). However while creating partition in `parted` by `mkpart swap 1 500`, I get the following error as usual.

```
(parted) mkpart swap 1 500
Error: Partition(s) 1 on /dev/mapper/luks_device have been written, but we have been
unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a
result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making
further changes.
Ignore/Cancel?
```

What do **Ignore** and **Cancel** mean? What are their differences? Even if I type "Cancel", the partition is still created.

Comment: I notice that if I choose "Ignore", there will be a message `Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.` upon parted quit. This message does not show up if "Cancel" was chosen. As mentioned, partition is created in both cases. I am still examinating the actual differences performed on the partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parted asks this question when the partition table is already written to the disk (and the write was successful) so the partition exists and only thing that's left is to tell kernel to re-read the partition table. That's a simple syscall (`BLKRRPART`) and it failed so parted can only inform you about that now.

The only difference between the *Ignore* and *Cancel* answer in this case is whether the call returns success (in case you choose *Ignore*) or failure (in case you choose *Cancel*). So the question doesn't really make sense in interactive mode because you are not checking the return code, but it can make sense in batch mode or when using libparted instead of parted.

In batch mode the command return code is set accordingly to your choice.

For *Ignore* it returns 0

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdc rm 1
Warning: Partition /dev/sdc1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
Error: Partition(s) 1 on /dev/sdc have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You
should reboot now before making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel? Ignore                                                     
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

$ echo $?                                              
0
```

And for *Cancel* it returns 1:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdc rm 1
Warning: Partition /dev/sdc1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
Error: Partition(s) 1 on /dev/sdc have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You
should reboot now before making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel? Cancel

$ echo $?
1
```

The missing *Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.* is also one visible difference. It's simply not printed by parted when the command is considered unsuccessful.

Note: In the example above I've tried to remove a partition in use to get the same error you got, it's a different situation but the behaviour is the same, the error message comes from the same libparted function to commit changes to the disk.